# Include jsp page in Wordpress without iframe

Tags: html, jsp, iframe, ssl, include

Is there a way to include a jsp page into a Wordpress widget (plain html widget) without an iframe?
I don't want to use an iframe because iframes cause problems with mixed content when using SSL.

Comment: have you tried loading the page with jquery?

Comment: I solved it by "copying" the html content from the jsp into the wordpress widget.

Comment: that sounds better im glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you say "iframes cause promlems with mixed content when using SSL" please elaborate more. is it the security warning pop up that's annoying?

For example, if the jsp page that you're trying to include in Wordpress lives on the same server

```
<iframe src="/wp-content/page.jsp" />
```

If your navigation page is being served from a separate host and you're being forced to use something like this

```
<iframe src="://externalhost/page.jsp" />
```

which will have the "insecure content" message alert in your browser.

if thats the problem, move the navigation application to the same server so you can use a relative URL.

Comment: That's the problem, the annoying warning popup which will be shown on each page, beacuse my iframe is included in the footer.
The problem of the iframe is that it contains a form which contains a non https-link as Post-action.